# Backbone.Marionette itemView event bubbling Issue

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

**I have a list of Teams and in Team a list of Tasks. The JSON data looks like this:**

```
{
    {"teamId":38,
     "teamName":"Analytics",
     "tasks":{
        {
            "taskId":93561,
            "taskName":"Analytics Country Report"
        }
      }
    },
    {"teamId":32,
     "teamName":"Client Service - Team Beaumont",
     "tasks":{
        {
            "taskId":93558,
            "taskName":"Project Management"
        }
      }
    },
    {"teamId":34,
     "teamName":"Copy",
      "tasks":{
        {
            "taskId":93580,
            "taskName":"Copy"
        }
      }
    },
    {"teamId":48,
     "teamName":"Engineering  - Team LZ",
     "tasks":{
        {
            "taskId":93573,
            "Front-end Development"
        },
        {
            "taskId":93562,
            "taskName":"Quality Control"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**My views:**

```
View.SchedulingTask = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: 'resource-planning/scheduling/templates/_scheduling-task',
    className: 'scheduling-task-handle',

    initialize: function() {
        var _this = this;
        App.vent.on( "scheduling:task:remove:" + _this.model.get('taskId'), function(){
            console.log('Task removed' + _this.model.get('taskId');
            _this.trigger('task:remove');
            _this.remove();
        })
    },
});

View.SchedulingTeam = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: 'resource-planning/scheduling/templates/_scheduling-team',
    itemView: View.SchedulingTask,

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = _this.model.get('tasks');
        this.on('itemview:task:remove', function(itemView){
            console.log("Team: task removed: " + _this.model.get('teamId'));
    // If the collection is empty, I need to remove the team as well
        });
    }
});
```

**Somewhere in another view I trigger the following event: I want task 93558 to be removed.**
App.vent.trigger("scheduling:task:remove:93558");

What I expect to happen is for to see is:

> > 'Task removed 93558'
> >
> > "Team: task removed: 32"

But what is see is:

> > 'Task removed 93558'
> >
> > "Team: task removed: 48"

Seems like the itemView event bubbling is not bubbling to the right CollectionView.

Please can someone shed some light on this for me.

Comment: What happens if you do `_.bindAll(this);` instead of `var _this = this;`? Yeah, I know you're probably not working on this anymore, but I'm wondering it has something to do with how `this` is being bound. Or perhaps you need to add one or the other statement in the body of `View.SchedulingTeam.initialize`.